# Batch files: How to capture output of a function in a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Newbie to Batch scripting here. I'm trying to capture the output of a [Batch 'function'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149217/4077294) (not exactly since Batch lacks built-in support for functions) to a variable. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto main

:: Functions
:runps
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "%1"
goto :eof

:appendToPath
set OLDPATHPS="[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
for /f %%i in ('call :runps %OLDPATHPS%') do ^
    set OLDPATH=%%i
:: ...
goto :eof

:main
call :appendToPath
```

When I run this I get the following output from the console:

```
Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Call` establishes a new `cmd` instance which cannot access a batch label in the old instance.

Solutions would include outputting the result to a file and reading the file or possibly

```
for /f %%i in ('%runps% "%OLDPATHPS%"') do (
    set OLDPATH=%%i
)
```

where `runps` has been set to `powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command`