# Function is not called in .bat file

Tags: function, batch-file

I'm creating a simple `.bat` file to open Android emulator from a new command prompt window and then print a value in the first window. However the function `:Display` seems doesn't get executed. When I click on `.bat` file, new prompt is opened and emulator is started but the first window is immediately closed. How can I make first window execute the `:Display` function?

```sh
cd "C:/Users/Pavindu/Downloads/Sdk/emulator"
start cmd /k emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28
call :Display
:Display
echo.  here the myDosFunc function is executing a group of commands
echo.  it could do a lot of things
```

Comment: Writing `pause` before the `exit` command still closes the windows?

Comment: but you are telling it to exit?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I modified the code as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149217/8810941). But the first window still closes after opening new window.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for lines `3` and `4`.

Comment: Like this the code is going to execute two times the `:Diplay` routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd "C:/Users/Pavindu/Downloads/Sdk/emulator"

start cmd /k emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28

REM we can also use a goto :Display with a pause as the last command
call :Display

REM insert more commands here after display call
pause
exit /B

:Display
echo here the myDosFunc function is executing a group of commands
echo it could do a lot of things
```

Comment: Like this the code is going to execute two times the `:Display` routine!

Comment: @Compo as far as I can understand no because of the `start cmd`. Can be `call cmd` going to execute it two times?

Comment: I see :Display getting called twice.  You either need goto :EOF or exit /b after the call :Display line.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SNR, your example above, changes directory to the location of the emulator executable, despite it using the incorrect path separators, and not specifically designating the drive. Then it opens a new `cmd` instance, (in a separate window, unrelated to the rest of this script), and immediately runs `call :Display`, which then returns to the point directly after that `call`. As there's nothing to tell your script not to continue, it will proceed to run the code under the `:Display` label, exiting at the `exit /b`. As I stated, it is running the `:Display` labelled code twice!

Comment: @Compo then I am missing something. The test I ran just execute one time `:Display` I understand because of the `exit \b` at the end of the subroutine. When I'll get home I am going to re-do the test.

Comment: @Compo you are right! I re-done the test and it was executing `:Display` twice. Somehow, I missed the first testing process. Thanks very much. I am going to edit the post so it works properly.

Comment: @Compo And also re-reading your comment I see how works the what i missed. Therefore a `goto` should work fine.